# How would you go about internationalizing Products?

Tags: product, localization

Here's my problem :

I have a database of products that are localized : the same product (primary key) will have a different name, different characteristics depending on the country and the language of commercialization. ex: the same product is called "hoover" in the US and "aspiradora" in Mexico but it really is the same product
What would be the best way to manage this in Salesforce ?

1. Keep a single Product record for each unique key and use a custom object for localized data.
   In this scenario, I'm really worried about the product name which is used in lookups everywhere...Salesforce is not too great on managing free text translations
2. Duplicate produts : one product record for each country/language which will allow the user to use the right product with the right information
   This scenario is not great in terms of good practice since a product unique key is duplicated and we can quickly end up with a million product records

Any suggestion ?

Note that I'm not looking to segregate product data, product catalogs are irrelevant to my specific problem

Comment: Are your products the Salesforce standard Product2 object, or a custom object?

Comment: They are the standard Product 2